# Find the range and the locus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Question:

$$ 0\le \arg(z -2+2i)^{\frac13} \le \frac{\pi}{4}$$
And $$\Im(z) - \Re(z) +4\ge 0$$
(a) State the range of $\arg(z +2i)$

(b) The locus of the complex number $w$ is defined by $| w +2i| =k$ , where $k$ is a real positive constant . Find the range od values of $k$ such that the loci of $w $and $z$ intersect.

I totally do not know how to deal with  $z^{1/3}$ in the aforementioned inequality . Could you show me how to use it in order to find out a solution for this question 
. Thank you.

Comment: Is the 1/3 inside the arg function or outside?

Comment: It is inside the arg function

Answer (score 2):

**So sorry for the careless mistake. I have edited it below.**

We starts with
$$0\le \arg(z- 2+2i)^{\frac13} \le \frac{\pi}{4}$$
So
$$0\le \frac13\arg(z -(2-2i)) \le \frac{\pi}{4}$$
Giving
$$0\le \arg(z -(2-2i)) \le \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

So you have
[image]

So
$$0\le \arg(z +2i) \le \frac{3\pi}{4}$$
too.

Part (b) is just drawing a circle. I believe you can attempt on your own. The diagram below will already give away some answer.

[image]